# how to expand and collapse a mixed list of shown and hidden elements (filtered divs) without showing the hidden ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm basically new to coding but i have this LONG list of products which i need to filter according to certain criteria plus a show more/less function. The issues are: **1.** When i filter elements, some categories have less items than the default set, **2.** if the shown element's total height is is shorter i need the container's height to match that height (i set a max-height but then it won't increase when the filter changes the number of products or i try to expand the list to show other hidden products) **3.** if a filter is applied and the list is longer than the default lenght shown, if i use the function to show more items, the hidden elements that do not belong to that category become visible.

Here is the actual jquery script, the html is so long i'm not posting it complete, but i'll post an example of the product setup.

jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var productList = $("#product_list:nth-child(3n+1):visible").height(); /*$("#product_list:nth-child(3n+1):visible").each(function(){productList += $(this).height();});*/
  var counter = 0;
  //filter functions
  $("ul#filters li a.button").click(function() {
    $("ul#filters li a.button").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    if ($(this).hasClass("active") == true) {

      var act = $(this).attr("id");

      $(".product:not(#" + act + ")").fadeOut(800);
      $(".product#" + act + "").fadeIn(800);
      $(".products .product:nth-child(4n+1)").css("border-left-width", 0);
      $("#product_list:last-child:visible").css("border-right", "2px dashed #008140");

      if (act == "all") {
        $(".product").fadeIn(800);
      } else {
        if ($(".product:last:visible") >= $(".product:last")) {
          //$("#loadmore").css("display", "none");
          $(".product:last:visible").css("border-right", "2px dashed #008140");
        }
      }
    }
  });
  //show more -show less
  $("#loadmore").click(function showNext() {
    $("#product_list").animate({
      height: productList + 3000
    }, 800);
    $(".product:hidden:lt(20)").slideDown();
    $("#showless").css("display", "block");
    counter = counter + 20;
    productList = productList + 3000;

    if ($(".product:last").is(":visible")) {
      $("#product_list").css("max-height", (productList - 2300));
      $("#product_list:last-child:visible").css("border-right", "2px dashed #008140");
      $("#loadmore").css("display", "none");
    }
    if ($("."))
  });

  $("#showless").click(function showLess() {
    //$(".product:visible:gt("+(counter-1)+")").slideUp()
    $("#product_list").animate({
      height: productList - 3000
    }, 800);
    counter = counter - 20;
    productList = productList - 3000;

    if (productList == 3000) {
      $("#showless").css("display", "none");
    }
    if ($("#loadmore").css("display", "none")) {
      $("#loadmore").css("display", "block");
    }
  });
});
```

product HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Row -->
  <div class="row" id="product_list">
    <!-- Product -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 product" id="belleza">
      <!-- Entry -->
      <div class="entry">
        <figure class="entry-thumbnail">
          <a href="#"><img alt="" src="../resources/images/productos/Shampoo-neutro.png"/></a>
        </figure>
        <div class="entry-body">
          <h3 class="entry-title">
            <a href="#">Shampoo Petra Neutro<br/></a>
          </h3>
          <h2 class="entry-title">
            <select id="presentaciones">
              <option id="shampoo-neutro260">Frasco Dosificador x260ml</option>
            </select>
          </h2>
          <h2 class="entry-title" id="disponible">Disponibles: <span class="unidades" id="shampoo-neutro">10</span>
          </h2>
          <span class="price"><ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>12.00</span></ins>
          <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>15.00</span></del></span>
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="button add_to_cart_button" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Entry -->
    </div>
    <!--End Col -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I reformatted your JS, but your HTML wasn't valid enough for the online tool I used to make any sense of. You might want to clean that up yourself if you want to facilitate answers. As is, it's pretty illegible.

Comment: thanks, i've tried to reformat a little the html, but it is mostle for context, the real problem im having is with the javascript/jquery part. @1252748